# If $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\},$ why is $\Sigma^* \times \Sigma^* $ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$, why is $|\Sigma^*\times\Sigma^*| = \aleph_0$?

Why isn't $\Sigma^*\times\Sigma^*$ uncountable? 
Thank you.

Comment: What's the definition of $A^*$?

Comment: Because you can find an easy way to count the words on $\Sigma$, and so the pair of words on $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume $\star$ refers to Kleene-star. Recall that 
$$
\Sigma^{\star}=\left\{ \varepsilon,a,b,c,aa,ab,ac,ba,bb,bc,ca,cb,cc\ldots\right\} .
$$
In this form, this is clearly countable, but we will construct an
injective map $f\colon\Sigma^{\star}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ for instructive
purposes regardless. Note that there are only $\left|\Sigma\right|^{n}$
strings of length $n$ in $\Sigma^{\star}$. Let $g\left(n\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\left|\Sigma\right|^{j}$.
Since there are only finitely many strings of length $n$, we can
easily construct a map from the strings of length $n$ (where $n>0$)
to the set $$\left\{ g\left(n\right)+1,g\left(n\right)+2,\ldots,g\left(n\right)+\left|\Sigma\right|^{n}\right\}.$$
Finally, we map $\varepsilon$ to 0.

To finish, we note that the Cartesian product of a countable set is
countable. To prove this, try and construct an injection from $\mathbb{N}^{2}$
to $\mathbb{N}$ (you might already be familiar with the pictorial proof for $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{N}$). For a proof of this, see [this page on proofwiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable).

Comment: No problem; happy counting!